# Tests not running in Testcafe getting error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

New to TestCafe .. just copied the code [from their site](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/#writing-test-code) and executed it.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
        .click('#submit-button');
    });
```

The browsers are connected successfully but script is not executed and got error after some time

```
Nimits-MacBook-Pro:TestCafe nimit$ testcafe chrome demo.js 
ERROR Was unable to open the browser "chrome:" due to error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.callee$0$0$ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/lib/api/find-window.js:111:36)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:72:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:334:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:105:21)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:72:40)
    at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:146:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:154:13
```

#### Environment

nodejs version - 10.16.0
npm - 6.9.0
OS - MACOS catalina
TestCafe - 1.6.0

Comment: Could you please add the code, or link to the section on their site?

Comment: import { Selector } from 'testcafe';


fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test("My first test", async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
        .click('#submit-button')
});

Comment: link to the code. 
"https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/"

Comment: Thanks. That error is curious - browser was connected successfully but also couldn't be opened? Can you run `testcafe -b` and double check Chrome is listed?

Comment: I think version of Node is a problem. Can you update Node and npm and see if error still occur?

Comment: @lostlemon i tried the command all the browser are listed properly also I have updated the node & npm version to latest , but still no luck

Comment: Although v1.6.0 added support for macOS Catalina, I suppose it could still be a bug. Maybe open an issue on GitHub? https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues

Comment: Seems to be the case , will open a ticket for this any way . Seems Selenium is the ultimate winner . Personally was impressed with this solution but  its not working at all :)

Comment: @SumitBhatnagar,

Could you please check that you granted permissions for TestCafe Browser Tools? Please follow the `System Preferences` - `Security & Privacy` - `Screen Recording`/`Automations` tabs. You should see that TestCafe Browser Tools is allowed to use. If you do not see these permissions, please try to execute the following commands: `tccutil reset AppleEvents` and `tccutil reset ScreenCapture`. Then, try to run TestCafe again. It will ask you for permissions. After all permissions are granted, the browser should start successfully.

Comment: @AlexKamaev -  You pointed to the right nerve, it does solved the problem....